# Why are values inserted into postgis columns of type geometry in quotes?

Tags: postgis

I'm figuring out how to use the `PostGIS` extension, and I found a nice tutorial: http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geometries.html.

First the tutorial directs to create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE geometries (
    name varchar,
    geom geometry
);
```

Then insert into that table

```
insert into geometries (name, geom)
values
    ('Point', 'point(0 0)');
```

Then, looking at what other column types I can use with the `PostGIS` addon, I found that I can use the `point` type directly:

```
create table points (
    name varcar,
    point point
);
insert into points (name, point)
values 
    ('point 1', point(0, 1));
```

(Notice that the inserted value into the `point` column is NOT wrapped in quotes)

Trying to insert a point into the `geometries` table without wrapping the value in a quote fails:

```
insert into geometries (name, geom)
values
    ('Point', point(0 0));
```

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "0"

This seems like it might be significant... *If a column of type `point` allows for inserting values defined via that type (`point(0 0)`) - **I assume this isn't a normal SQL function call? -**, why can't I do the same for a column of type `geometry`?*

Comment: you mix up a few things; the plain `POINT` type is a native PostgreSQL geometric type, independent from PostGIS and incompatible with it's functionality. Most types come with built in (implicit) type cast from common input types; this is why PostGIS `GEOMETRY` type accepts a valid WKT string representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [`point`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-geometric.html) is not a PostGIS type, but a native PostgresSQL type. The two are not compatible.

Creating a geometry from a string is one way. You can of course create a (PostGIS) point geometry via [`ST_Point`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html) or [`ST_MakePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html)

```
select st_point(1,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

For either type, you could insert with or without quotes. What caused the error was the missing comma (which is required only in SQL):

```
postgres=# select point(0 0);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "0"
LINE 1: select point(0 0);
                       ^
postgres=# select point(0, 0);
 point
-------
 (0,0)
(1 row)
```

(For the `geometry` type, the `point` value would be automatically converted.)

Comment: According to the answers above... this is misleading as it implies the `point` type and `'point'` `geometry` type are comparable. which the other answers say isn't correct

Comment: You could force the cast (`point(0,0)::geometry`) but it is not automatic